# Group-based trajectory modelling in R

Tags: r, longitudinal

I've been looking for a way to conduct group-based trajectory modeling in R with no avail.  Something along the lines of what PROC TRAJ (http://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/bjones/index.htm) accomplishes in SAS.  Does anyone know of a similar package in R?
My outcome of interest (the model input) is categorical so i need something that can handle that.

Answer (score 4):

The only package I've been able to find for this in R is *crimCV*. [Here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/crimCV/index.html) it is on Cran, and [here](http://www.probability.ca/jeff/ftpdir/cross.pdf) is a working paper by the authors of the package on how it's done. I have not yet investigated this myself (and it seems like it hasn't been updated for years), but [this](https://andrewpwheeler.wordpress.com/2014/08/12/estimating-group-based-trajectory-models-using-spss-and-r/) page describes using it to fit a set of trajectories.

Comment: thank you, I actually went with lcmm and it works very well for my question.